# What is the name of this battery connector?

Tags: batteries, identification, connector, lithium-ion, adapter

What is the name of this battery connector?

[image]

This is the link to the [battery](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003668375149.html) itself.

Comment: I'd would just cut the connector off and replace it with a connector I actually wanted to use. You're going to have to put a connector on whatever the battery is plugging into anyways. When cutting through battery wires CUT ONE WIRE AT A TIME!!! Or else you will produce a dangerous short circuit.

Comment: Fit your own connector - a common sense solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a molex connector. You'll have to find the pins for it. Here is a link:
https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/crimp_housings/0003091022